# Is SlimROMS one thing or many?

Tags: custom-roms

I was looking at some threads to download a custom firmware when I noticed one thing as a thanking gesture, developers or maintainers were thanking SlimROMS team. I went to [SlimROMS](http://slimroms.net) website and its forums as well but I couldn't pin point:

1) Is SlimROMS one thing or many?

2) I found somethreads featuring names like Slimsaber or Slimkat which shares some common features. Are they SlimROMs? It's really confusing to me. Are there other ROMs with naming convention Slim[XYZ]?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my answer after a bit more search.

I don't know why they use 's' and calls it SLIMROMs but Slim + Jelly Bean = SlimBean, [Slim + Kitkat = SlimKat](https://crowdin.com/project/slimroms) and [Slim + Lollipop (LP) = SlimLP](http://www.slimroms.net/index.php/news/524-slimlp).

[SlimSaber](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/discussion-thread-rom-5-1-1-5-0-2-4-4-4-30-06-slimsaber-bacon-slimlp-unofficial-builds.319937/) on the other hand is an unofficial build of SlimLP. I suppose 'Saber' comes from custom toolchain Sabermod.